# c3 charts - Getting values from controller but not displaying in chart

Tags: ajax, jsp, charts, c3.js

Created an application which contains some charts.  Here is my code which gets values from controller(no error in console  or in code), but values not displaying in chart.

```
 function bmi()
 {
   var measuresArray = [];
   var dimensionArray = [];
   var acc = $("#accountName").val();
   var year = $("#yearBased").val();
  var dat = JSON.stringify({"accountName" : acc,"yearBased" : year});
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "xyz.html",
    cache : false,
    data : dat,
    async : false,
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(dataList) {

        $.each(dataList,function(i,dataList){
                    measuresArray.push(dataList);
                    dimensionArray.push(i);
        });
        $("#bmiPriorityDiv").empty();
        chartGenerator("#bmiPriorityDiv",measuresArray,dimensionArray,"Month",'bar');
}
});
}
```

Value i am getting like this :
measuresArray : Array(12)
0:0.6365796
1:0.6107492
2:0.5553435
3:0.7089947
4:0.6671214
5:0.7635135
6:0.6294821
7:0.728863
8:0.8280423
9:0.7690531
10:0.65411764
11:0.5833333

and for dimensionArray:
Array(12)
0:"June"
1:"October"
2:"December"
3:"May"
4:"September"
5:"March"
6:"July"
7:"January"
8:"February"
9:"April"
10:"August"
11:"November"

But i am getting empty chart. Please help...

Comment: Stuck here for 1 day. pls help...

Comment: Got the value. Need to give columns:[measuresArray], in chartGenerator. Before i was given columns:measuresArray. Now Working fine.